# How to conditionally re-position crystal reports XI objects

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am using Crystal Reports XI as a Stand alone and not using Visual Studio. I have text box objects which dynamically grow in size according to the data. If the text box grows and has 2 lines of data instead of 1, I want the text box below it to be automatically re-positioned down. Is there a way to do use conditional programming to achieve this.
At the moment I have a formula that counts how many characters are in the text box objects so I can use this in my conditional statement but am wondering about how to code the object properties and methods such as the X position of the object. 
Thanks.

Comment: put text object it in separate section

Comment: If I understand you correctly I already have the duplicate text object in a separate section and suppress the unwanted section and it works but I was hoping that I could use code to re-position the one text object. Thanks for your input

Comment: Can u provide screen copy